# Regular Expression to parse string

Tags: c#, regex

I have potential `strings` like this. The fist few `characters` are a symbol that can be one to a few letters, but could contain weird characters like "/". Then the next six `characters` are always a `date`, YYMMDD where YY,MM,DD are always `integers`, but are always padded to the left with a `0` as shown. This is followed by a single character that is always 'C' or 'P', then finally a `double`.

```
AAPL220819C152.5
AAPL220819P195
AAPL220902P187.5
AAPL220819C155
AAPL220930C180
```

What is a `regular expression` that `parses` these strings into its constituent parts,

```
Symbol,
Date,
COP,
Strike
```

**fast**?

So the expected output would be:

```
"AAPL220819C152.5" {Symbol = "AAPL", Date = 2022-08-19, COP = "C", Strike = 152.5 }
"AAPL220819P195"   {Symbol = "AAPL", Date = 2022-08-19, COP = "P", Strike = 195.0}
```

I have seen similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402379/how-can-i-use-regex-to-parse-an-occ-option-symbol) but I don't understand enough to modify it.

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Comment: can you show what the expected outcome would look like from one of your examples?

Comment: See Original Post for example of expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestParsingRegex("AAPL220819C152.5", "AAPL220819P195", "AAPL220902P187.5", "AAPL220819C155", "AAPL220930C180");
        }

        private static void TestParsingRegex(params string[] strings)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"([A-Z]+)(\d{6})([CP]{1})(.*)");
            foreach (var s in strings)
            {
                var match = regex.Match(s);
                foreach (var g in match.Groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(g);
                }
            }
        }
```

it should have the following output:

```
AAPL220819C152.5
AAPL
220819
C
152.5
AAPL220819P195
AAPL
220819
P
195
AAPL220902P187.5
AAPL
220902
P
187.5
AAPL220819C155
AAPL
220819
C
155
AAPL220930C180
AAPL
220930
C
180
```

Notice that the first group is the entire string

This regex uses groups to get the desired parsing like so:

`([A-Z]+)` all upper case letters up to the next group

`(\d{6})` exactly six digits

`([CP]{1})` exactly one `C` or `P` character

`(.*)` everything else